# asp net core web api не принимает запросы с клиента multipart

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, asp.net-web-api

код который работает на сервере

```
[HttpPost("Add")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody]RequestAdd person)
    {

        if(person != null){
            return Ok("good");
        }

        return Ok("false");
    }
```

здесь я создаю объекты и отправляю его в метод

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Uploads(Person person, List<FileInfo> files)
            {


            try
            {
            var jsonToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.None);
            var multipart = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            var body = new StringContent(jsonToSend, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            multipart.Add(body, "JsonDetails");


            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(item.FullName));

                multipart.Add(fileContent, item.FullName);
            }


            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);

            return client.PostAsync("Add", multipart);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }  
    }
```

здесь я отправляю пост запрос на сервер

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Method2();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            static void Method2()
            {
                UploadMultiPart uploadMultiPart = new UploadMultiPart();

                List<FileInfo> fileInfos = new List<FileInfo>()
                {
                    new FileInfo(@"C:\asd\full-metal-jacket.png"),
                    new FileInfo(@"C:\asd\full-metal-jacket.png"),
                    new FileInfo(@"C:\asd\full-metal-jacket.png")
                };

                Person person = new Person
                {
                Name = "Adilbek",
                SureName = "Ramazanov",
                Position = "God",
                Group = "heaven",
                Phone = 123123
                };

            var result = loadMultiPart.Uploads(person,fileInfos).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Status is " + result.StatusCode);
        }
```

на сервер идут запросы но значение null у Person, и одна картинка проходит